# Material UI for React "Cannot read property of 'between'.. " when trying to use theme.breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, breakpoints

Cannot read property of 'between' / 'up'.. when trying to use theme.breakpoints.between.

I've read through the other stackoverflow answers and some of the issues here: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues and the only solution seems to be using `ThemeProvider` or `MuiThemeProvider`, which I've tried but error still exists.

Component file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";

import Logo from "../assets/logo/logo";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1
  },
  logo: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
      padding: "5em"
    }
  }
});

class Tools extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid container className={classes.logo}>
          <Grid item className={classes.logo}>
            <Logo name="some-logo" />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Tools.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Tools);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import MuiThemeProvider from "@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
             <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Home />} />
             </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Maybe error with something else, because I got it working with default theme: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vn44w0ly3

Comment: Yeah thanks - it works when I use it at the component level like your sample. I was trying to inject it globally so I don't have to call it for every component. Would you have a working sample of it injected at the root level ie. index.js ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `withStyles` should have been imported from `"@material-ui/**core**/styles"` in the component file.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue with sloppy installation of material-ui without checking the version used in the project.

Rolled back to the previous version (listed below) and the issue was resolved.

Rolled back versions of:
@emotion/react: 11.4.1 from 11.5.0, and
@mui/material: 5.0.0 from 5.0.4